# Ignore external dependencies and standard library in `godoc` output

Tags: go, godoc

I have a Go project which uses Go Modules. I'd like to use `godoc` to generate the documentation for this project's packages. Currently, I'm using:

```sh
godoc -http=":6060"
```

This generates the documentation for the project, sure, but it also generates the standard library's and imported dependencies' documentation.

Is there any way to ignore these? They feel redundant at best. If it isn't possible to ignore them, is there any way to use `godoc` or `go doc` to generate documentation in HTML format for the project's packages?

Comment: No, that command does not _generate_ the docs. It simply starts a server that serves the docs that are already generated. Godoc is just comments (and exported symbols). You generate it when you write your code. See [Godoc: documenting Go code](https://blog.golang.org/godoc-documenting-go-code) from the official Go blog.

Comment: Gotcha, thanks for the explanation/link @Flimzy

Answer (score -3):

These are the options available to `godoc`:

```
$ godoc --help
usage: godoc package [name ...]
    godoc -http=:6060
  -all
        include unexported identifiers in command-line mode
  -analysis string
        comma-separated list of analyses to perform (supported: type, pointer). See http://golang.org/lib/godoc/analysis/help.html
  -ex
        show examples in command line mode
  -goroot string
        Go root directory (default "/usr/local/go")
  -html
        print HTML in command-line mode
  -http string
        HTTP service address (e.g., ':6060')
  -httptest.serve string
        if non-empty, httptest.NewServer serves on this address and blocks
  -index
        enable search index
  -index_files string
        glob pattern specifying index files; if not empty, the index is read from these files in sorted order
  -index_interval duration
        interval of indexing; 0 for default (5m), negative to only index once at startup
  -index_throttle float
        index throttle value; 0.0 = no time allocated, 1.0 = full throttle (default 0.75)
  -links
        link identifiers to their declarations (default true)
  -maxresults int
        maximum number of full text search results shown (default 10000)
  -notes string
        regular expression matching note markers to show (default "BUG")
  -play
        enable playground in web interface
  -q    arguments are considered search queries
  -server string
        webserver address for command line searches
  -src
        print (exported) source in command-line mode
  -tabwidth int
        tab width (default 4)
  -templates string
        load templates/JS/CSS from disk in this directory
  -timestamps
        show timestamps with directory listings
  -url string
        print HTML for named URL
  -v    verbose mode
  -write_index
        write index to a file; the file name must be specified with -index_files
  -zip string
        zip file providing the file system to serve; disabled if empty
```

Comment: I am aware and have read through it (as well as https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/tools/cmd/godoc), but unless I'm missing something, none of those seem to do what I'm asking

Comment: If I'm not missing anything, I guess it's just not possible at this stage ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @Aquarthur: That's because what you are asking isn't a thing, because you misunderstand what `godoc` does.

Comment: So I am missing something then :P Fair enough, thanks for the explanation!

Comment: @Flimzy I guess the question is why would anyone want to serve stdlib docs? Why is that useful? The intuitive use case for a tool like godoc is to serve docs for my project, not my entire dependency tree, and certainly not the entire stdlib and every library I have installed locally.

Comment: @wbr: So what you're saying is, if you're browsing your local project's godoc, and you see a function that takes an argument of type `http.Transport`, you _want_ that link to be broken?

Comment: Aside from that obviously broken use-case, it's useful to serve stdlib docs if you're working without a reliable Internet connection, as many commuters do.

Comment: Oh, and one other good reason to serve stdlib docs: There are different versions of the stdlib, but the online docs always reflect the most recent stable version. If you're using a pre-release, or an older version of the stdlib, your only option is local docs.